# VBA ComboBox not displaying values

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

Trying to use the ComoboBox with VBA and it only displays 1 empty row when you click on the down arrow. I have never used ComboBox before and am still a beginner to VBA.

```
Private Sub ComboBoxT_Change()
     ComboBoxT.AddItem "apple"
     ComboBoxT.AddItem "orange"
     ComboBoxT.AddItem "banana"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Saagar said, they way that the code is currently written, it will only add the items into your combobox if there is a change in the combobox. The code that I would use would look like this:

```
Private Sub UserFormName_Activate()
   ComboBoxT.AddItem "apple"
   ComboBoxT.AddItem "orange"
   ComboBoxT.AddItem "banana"
end sub
```

The easiest way to achieve this is in the user form creator, double click on the userform frame. This should show the code you would be working with, then from the top dropdown bars (the first one might say either "UserForm" or "General") you can select "Userform" in the first one and "Activate" in the second one. That should give you a good place to start, and the items you wanted added to the ComboBox should be right there, ready to go. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

The Event you selected to add items to the ComboBox will only be fired if there is a change in the ComboBox. You need to enter this piece of code to add new items to the ComboBox in another event which is fired before you want to use the ComboBox.

Most cases, it is done at the Form_Load event, so that you have the items available inside the ComboBox by the time the Form is loaded completely.

Try the below

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
     ComboBoxT.AddItem "apple"
     ComboBoxT.AddItem "orange"
     ComboBoxT.AddItem "banana"
End Sub
```